# Google Sign in on local virtual host

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, sign

Now is 2020. I need to implement Google Sign in for my page but I cant allow using local virtual host to test it. There should be some white list but I cant find any in Google developers console. Can somebody send me a path->to->settings for this? I am lost in their admin...

Answer (score 0):

So I have it. Need to go to [credentials page](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) and then click on Client IDs edit icon. There it is. Vrrrr...